# Передача информации из фрагмента в фрагмент, которые находятся во ViewPager

Tags: java, android

Как можно реализовать передачу информации из одного фрагмента в другой, когда оба эти фрагмента находятся в `ViewPager`?

Есть класс `MainActivity`, в котором я реализую `ViewPager` со своим собственным FragmentPagerAdapter и также TabLayout, который отображает эти фрагменты как "табы".

**Код инициализации `ViewPager` и `TabLayout` в `MainActivity`:**

```
private void initTabs() {
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        TabsPagerFragmentAdapter adapter = new TabsPagerFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
```

**Код моего FragmentPagerAdapter:**

```
public class TabsPagerFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private String[] tabs;

    public TabsPagerFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        tabs = new String[]{
                "Описание",
                "Карта",
        };

    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabs[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return Fragment_ListFragment.getInstance();
            case 1:
                return Fragment_MapTab.getInstance();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabs.length;
    }
}
```

Так вот, моя задача заключается в том, что мне нужно например получить некое число в первом фрагменте и передать его во второй фрагмент, который содержится в этом же `ViewPager`. Потом второй фрагмент должен принять это число и на основании его "перестроить" свой вид (я так понимаю это число нужно будет принимать в `onCreateView` методе и все "перестройку" вида проводить в нем же). После того как второй фрагмент "перестроил" свой вид, нужно чтобы `ViewPager` открывал автоматически второй фрагмент(как я понял нужно использовать метод `setCurrentItem()`)

Собственно вопросы:

1.Как реализовать передачу данных и из одного фрагмента в другой?

2.И если я получу эти данные, то логику "перестройки" нужно описать в методе `onCreateView`?

**Коды фрагментов:**

Первый фрагмент(из которого я должен получить информацию, в данном случае - это позиция элемента в списке):

```
public class Fragment_ListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private ViewPager vp;

    public static Fragment_ListFragment getInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        Fragment_ListFragment fragment = new Fragment_ListFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        vp = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Constants.names);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        long a = id;
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), a + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        vp.setCurrentItem(Constants.TAB_MAP);
    }
}
```

Второй фрагмент(в нем я должен принять эту позицию):

```
public class Fragment_MapTab extends Fragment {
    public static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.fragment_map_tab;
    private View view;

    public static Fragment_MapTab getInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        Fragment_MapTab fragment = new Fragment_MapTab();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вопрос можно закрыть. Можно использовать такой подход:

В MainActivity нужно создать String переменную (Пусть будет TabFragment), и две функции для изменения и извлечения оной (String getTabFragment и void setTabFreagment). 
Во фрагменте которому нужно что-то передать создаем строку и присваиваем ей результат метода getTag().
Далее используя метод

```
((MainActivity)getActivity).setTabFragment(myTag)
```

мы передаем тег нашего фрагмента нашему вышестоящему активити (вместо MainActivity может быть любой другой активити). 
А во фрагменте из которого извлекается информация также создаем строку, например to, и присваиваем ей результат метода

```
((MyActivity)getActivity).getTabFragment().
```

Далее получаем наш фрагмент:

```
Fragment* fragment = (Fragment*)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(to);
```

где Fragment* - ваш класс фрагмента к которому вы хотите получить доступ.

Таким образом, получив наш fragment мы можем обращаться к нему напрямую, использовать например вызов метода onCreateView с передачей нужной информации в виде Bundle.

Полностью метод описан здесь http://android-er.blogspot.ru/2012/06/communication-between-fragments-in.html

Comment: почитайте про eventbus-ы