# Есть viewpager, в нем два фрагмента. Как передать строку из фрагмента в фрагмент?

Tags: android

В первом фрагменте есть tсp клиент, который при нажатии на кнопку отправляет сообщение, например `String massage="my massage";`. Как при нажатии на кнопку передать это сообщение из второго фрагмента?

Comment: Интерфейс, лапша между фрагментами и активностями

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Передача информации из фрагмента в фрагмент, которые находятся во ViewPager](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/455031/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%be-viewpager)

Comment: с тем ответом разобраться не смог слишком много кода для того чтобы передать всего одну строку

Comment: У вас немного неправильное определение понятия "слишком много кода" - например, один только [стандартный класс `View`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java#View) фреймворка Android содержит порядка 20 000 строк. Так что 3- 5 строчек, чтобы вывести одну строку, это никак не "много кода", если вы хотите этим заниматься, то уже сейчас должны понять, что десятью (и сотней) строчками полноценную программу не напишешь - это только учебные примеры маленькие по объему. Сама библиотека *EventBus* содержит тысячи строк кода.

Comment: я это все понимаю но в том ответе не 3 и даже не пять строчек ну или я просто не правильно понял а в  EventBus все намного проще.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добрый день! Используйте EventBus  http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/how-to-get-started/
Отличное решение для передачи данных в любые части проекта

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.Это именно то что я искал.